# Sending authenticated HTTP requests from ComputeEngine to AppEngine using the default service account

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, servlets, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

For a project that I'm currently developing, I need to expose a servlet (hosted on Google App Engine) to a Java executable which is hosted on Google Compute Engine (in the same project). Such servlet performs some maintenance tasks, so it should never be triggered by non-authorized users. So, the goal is to authorize the requests coming from the Google Compute Engine instance that is running the JAR executable.

In the past I've solved the same issue by having the servlet exposed on HTTPS and rely on a "shared secret", known both to AppEngine application and to the JAR running on the Compute Engine instance. In that way, the instance calls the specific servlet (which is public), then the servlet verifies if the secret is correct, and if so, the request is allowed.

I don't like this approach. For sure we can do something better using challenge-response authentication or by using some other authentication procedure (probably via asymmetric crypto signing). However, this is not what I want to do.

My preferred way of acheiving the same result would be by using the Compute Engine Default Service Account. I am pretty sure there is a way of creating a HTTP POST request on the compute engine and authenticate that via the default service account key. Then, on the servlet, I would rely on the UserService to check whether the request is coming from the ComputeEngine default service account, and if so, I would accept that.

However, I have not seen any documentation or code example that explains how to do that. I suspect there might be possible to perform an authenticated HTTPRequest using the default Compute Engine Service Sccount (maybe adding the Bearer JWT token as Authorization header?).

Has anyone tried something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [several options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/oauth/); OAuth is likely your best bet.

Comment: In the end I've decided to use Default Service Account from compute engine to generate a refreshtoken/token and send it over the Authorization header when posting to the HTTPS servlet on AppEngine. On the AppEngine side, I receive the token, validate it and if the validation pass I authorize the request.